# Set inclusion: map image of inverse image

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces, $A \subseteq X$, and $B \subseteq Y$. For a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, I am going to show that
$$
B \not\subseteq f[f^{-1}[B]]
$$
Let us test the proposition, for $y \in Y$,
$$
y \not\in f[f^{-1}[B]] \implies y\not\in B
$$

$$
y\not\in f[f^{-1}[B]]\\
\iff\not\exists a \in f^{-1}[B] ~\text{s.t.}~ f(a) = y\\
\iff \forall a \in f^{-1}[B], f(a) \neq y\\
\iff \forall a \in X, f(a)\in B \implies f(a) \neq y\\
\iff \forall a \in X, f(a) = y \implies y=f(a)\not\in B\\
?\iff \exists a \in X ~\text{s.t.}~ f(a) = y \implies y=f(a)\not\in B\\
\iff y\in f[X] \implies y\not\in B
$$
We can conclude that $y \not\in B$ only if $\exists a \in X$ s.t. $f(a)=y$ holds. Therefore, the proposition is not true in general.

On the other hand, if $f$ is subjective, that is, $f[X] = Y$, for all $y\in Y$, we can always find $a \in X$ s.t. $f(a)=y$. Finally, we get the last line added as
$$
\iff y \in Y \implies y\not\in B
$$
which can be summarized as
$$
y \not\in f[f^{-1}[B]] \implies y\not\in B
$$

Is this correct inference?

Comment: If $B$ is the empty set then $B \subseteq f[f^{-1}(B)]$. What you can prove is $B \subseteq f[f^{-1}(B)]$ need not always hold.